# Module for sidebar menu which appears in open atrium

Tags: 7, distributions

I wanted to know if any modules already exists for creating side bar menu which appears in open atrium. So that it expands only when required.

/** Update **/

Please see the image below. I am talking of the LHS black sidebar.

[image]

Comment: What you describe sounds like default Drupal behavior. Can you elaborate on what you are missing.

Comment: @googletorp - Please see the updated question with screenshot now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the [admin](http://drupal.org/project/admin) module.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the [Admin](http://drupal.org/project/admin) module.